# How to convert this Python code to R?

Tags: python, r, dataframe

,I need help with translating a python code into an R code.

I have a data frame df, that contains the column IndicatorOfDefault and I would like too generate a column named indvalues.

Example:

```
row number   IndicatorOfDefault   indvalues

823602                        P           0 

823603                        P           0

823604                  N1,N13,           8

823605                      N1,           1

823606                        P           0

823607         N1,N2,N3,N9,N10,          13

823608                        P           0
```

The code that I want to convert is the following:

```
df['indicators'] = df['IndicatorOfDefault'].str.split(',')

Nvalues = {'' : -1, 'P' : 0, 'N1' : 1, 'N2' : 2, 'N11' : 3, 'N12' : 4, 'N3' : 5, 'N4' : 6, 
           'N6' : 7, 'N10' : 8, 'N13' : 9, 'N5' : 10, 'N7' : 11, 'N8': 12, 'N9' : 13}

df['indvalues'] = df['indicators'].apply(lambda x: max([Nvalues.get(y,y) for y in x ]))
```

I would like to execute the same code in R, but I don't know how to write it in R.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance

Why is this question off topic? I don't understand what's wrong... I am new to this site, so I would appreciate if someone could explain why this specific problem doesn't belong here? I've read what's written in the help center, but i still don't know what's wrong.

I've managed to solve my problem in a different way. I get the result that I want - the most important indicator (it didn't needed to be a number necessary).

```
    df$ind <- "P"
for(i in c(1, 2, 11, 12, 3, 4, 6, 10, 13, 5, 7, 8, 9)){
       df <- transform(df, ind = ifelse(grepl(as.character(paste0("N",i,",")),IndicatorOfDefault),as.character(paste0("N",i)),ind))
    }
```

Example:

```
row number   IndicatorOfDefault         ind

823602                        P           P 

823603                        P           P

823604                  N1,N13,         N13

823605                      N1,          N1

823606                        P           P

823607         N1,N2,N3,N9,N10,          N9

823608                        P           P
```

Comment: untag python, `dput` your r data frame and paste into the question, describe what youre trying to do, and add your attempt(s)

Comment: @rawr: what do you mean by dput your r data frame?

Comment: The data frame I have is very big (61 columns and 823610 rows), that's why I posted a small example showing the rows 823602 to 823608 in the columns IndicatorOfDefault and indvalues (this column I would like to generate).

Comment: `dput(df[823602:823608, c('IndicatorOfDefault', 'indvalues')])`

Comment: This question is on-topic and should not have been put on hold. @rawr: Jasmina has a Python dataframe, not R (so there is no `dput()`). She wants to convert this Python code to equivalent R.

Comment: @smci: yes, you're right. I have a python code and I would like to convert it to an R code, but I'm not so familiar with either of these two languages, because so far I've used Stata and in college C++.

Comment: @Jasmina: I changed the title to the more direct *How to convert this Python code to R"*. That might reduce confusion.

Comment: @smci: thank you very much :)

Comment: Voting to leave closed: no effort shown; there are innumerate ways, choosing among which is really up to you. Instead, show what you've done and where you're stuck (if you're not, SO is not a free freelance site to do your work for you).

Comment: @smci that makes no sense, the data is not married to python so the language is irrelevant. if OP can read the data into r, then OP can dput it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since R does not have the dictionary object, the best translation will be a named list. Do note: R does not allow zero-length names, so *N0* is used. From there you can use R's `vapply()` and `strsplit()` to string split the column and find its corresponding max value. Specifically, `vapply()` as opposed to the standard `lapply()` is used to specify the output type as a numeric vector for dataframe column.

Below includes both scripts to show exact *result* columns renders with posted data.

**Python**

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = '''row number;IndicatorOfDefault;indvalues
823602;P;0
823603;P;0
823604;N1,N13,;8
823605;N1,;1
823606;P;0
823607;N1,N2,N3,N9,N10;13
823608;P;0'''

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(data), sep=";")

df['indicators'] = df['IndicatorOfDefault'].str.split(',')

Nvalues = {'' : -1, 'P' : 0, 'N1' : 1, 'N2' : 2, 'N11' : 3, 'N12' : 4, 'N3' : 5, 'N4' : 6, 
           'N6' : 7, 'N10' : 8, 'N13' : 9, 'N5' : 10, 'N7' : 11, 'N8': 12, 'N9' : 13}

df['result'] = df['indicators'].apply(lambda x: max([Nvalues.get(y,y) for y in x ]))

print(df)
#    row number IndicatorOfDefault  indvalues             indicators  result
# 0      823602                  P          0                    [P]       0
# 1      823603                  P          0                    [P]       0
# 2      823604            N1,N13,          8            [N1, N13, ]       9
# 3      823605                N1,          1                 [N1, ]       1
# 4      823606                  P          0                    [P]       0
# 5      823607    N1,N2,N3,N9,N10         13  [N1, N2, N3, N9, N10]      13
# 6      823608                  P          0                    [P]       0
```

**R**

```r
data = 'row number;IndicatorOfDefault;indvalues
823602;P;0
823603;P;0
823604;N1,N13,;8
823605;N1,;1
823606;P;0
823607;N1,N2,N3,N9,N10;13
823608;P;0'

df = read.table(text=data, sep=";", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Nvalues = list(N0=-1, P=0, N1=1, N2=2, N11=3, N12=4,
               N3=5, N4=6, N6=7, N10=8, N13=9, N5=10,
               N7=11, N8=12, N9=13)

df$indicators <- lapply(df$IndicatorOfDefault, function(i) {
     as.character(strsplit(i, ",")[[1]])
})

df$result <- vapply(df$indicators, function(i) {  
     max(as.numeric(Nvalues[i]))  
}, numeric(1))

df

#   row.number IndicatorOfDefault indvalues          indicators result
# 1     823602                  P         0                   P      0
# 2     823603                  P         0                   P      0
# 3     823604            N1,N13,         8             N1, N13      9
# 4     823605                N1,         1                  N1      1
# 5     823606                  P         0                   P      0
# 6     823607    N1,N2,N3,N9,N10        13 N1, N2, N3, N9, N10     13
# 7     823608                  P         0                   P      0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, but the code doesn't work. When I excute

Comment: df$indicators <- lapply(df$IndicatorOfDefault, function(i) {
     as.character(strsplit(i, ",")[[1]])
})

Comment: I get the following Error:

Comment: [7] ERROR:
object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: I've tried to run the code again and the first error disappeared, but now I get the error: [12] ERROR:
replacement has 0 rows, data has 823479. My understanding is that the function lapply doesn't return a vector.

Comment: What line errs out? Post shows code does work. Check the column names of data frame. Your original post did not have the **d** in *IndicatorOfDefault* capitalized. Python and R are case sensitive in this regard. Also, how is your updated post even near the original Python code? Aren't you supposed to max the numeric value of dictionary?

Comment: The line with lapply. But when I run the code again, now I get the error "non-character argument". I import my data from a csv file.

Comment: I'm sorry the d was a mistake, because I've translated the variable names into English. When I tried your code I used my original variable names.

Comment: I've tried to write the R code, which is the solution for my problem, before, but I got several error messages and it seemed it doesn't work, so I've tried to use an other solution - the Python code, that was written by a coworker.

Comment: But I did not know how to. So I asked for help here. The problem that I needed to solve was that I wanted to extract the most important indicator of all indicators that are listed in one row. My coworker used a solution through assigning numbers. 
Luckily I then managed to write my original R code in such a way that it now works.

Comment: Got it. Sorry this answer does not work for you. Likely your data does not reflect like it is posted here. If you were to copy this exact R code and run it, you will see it does work!

Comment: No, I'm sorry you wasted your time for me. I know that this work's, but I'm clueless why it doesn't work on my data frame. I've just started to learn R, so I'm not very good at this. Nevertheless, through your code I've learned something new, so I appreciate your help. Thank you very much.

Comment: One possibility is your *IndicatorOfDefault* column might be a factor type instead of character where `strsplit()` can be run. Notice in my answer here I read sample data with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`. Check the column with command: `str(df)`. Convert with `as.character()`. And no waste here! I love any chance to use `vapply()`!

Comment: Yes, you're right! The column is indeed a factor type and when I convert it, the code works :). The function str() is really awesome, I didn't know it before. Thank's, you really helped me.

Comment: Great! Please accept the answer (check mark to side of question) if it helped and to confirm resolution.